# Any util in jose to convert key from PEM to JWK for Ed25519?

Tags: jose

An Ed25519 `PEM` key pair was generated as below:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
NC4CAQAwBQYcK2VwBCIEIIWUb0/MoKaBxQkmmPlHIGyPfDQb/U3D6jQ+gMUGtvpa
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
NCowBQYDK2VwAyEAWFnlEbTVgD4TilnSzyDmZK16dm1IeQURtHFcLhSwmDo=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

In `jose 3.11.1`, the `parseJwk`, taking `JWK` input, is used to generate keys used in signing and verification. Is there utility in `jose` converting `PEM` key to `JWK` used in `paseseJwk` or with a 3rd party utility? I didn't find one for `nodejs` project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a KeyObject you don't need your keys in JWK format. It works with node's [KeyObject](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_keyobject) instances. So you can easily do

```js
const { createPublicKey, createPrivateKey } = require('crypto')

const publicKey = createPublicKey(pemPublicKey)
const privateKey = createPrivateKey(pemPrivateKey)
```

This is documented in the [KeyLike](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/v3.11.1/docs/types/types.keylike.md) interface the library uses in its docs.